# Finding common String within two Vector

Tags: scala

I'm attempting to find common values that occur in two vectors. For Example, for `vector1` and `vector2` find where the names are common. In this case `T("1")` & `T("3")` are common to both vectors so return

```
Set(T("1") , T("3"))
```

Below is my solution which returns the correct solution :

```
object FindCommon extends App {

  case class T(name: String)
  case class B(t: Seq[T])

  val vector1 = Vector(B(Seq(T("1") ,T("2") , T("3"))))
  val vector2 = Vector(B(Seq(T("1") , T("3"))))

  val f1 = vector1.map(m => m.t).flatten
  val f2 = vector2.map(m => m.t).flatten

  val common = f1.concat(f2).groupBy(i=>i).view.mapValues(_.size).toMap.filter(f => f._2 > 1).keys

  println("common : "+common)
}
```

prints

```
common : Set(T(1), T(3))
```

Is there a more elegant/idiomatic Scala solution to this problem? Although the above solution returns the correct result I think there may be simpler solutions, perhaps using `flatMap` and/or `fold`?

Comment: This solution assumes that each value is unique in each vector, are you sure about that? Also, it doesn't matter in which inner seq of each vector the elements are as long as they are in both vectors?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez Indeed, my solution for vectors:

  val vector1 = Vector(B(Seq(T("1") , T("1") ,T("2") , T("3"))))
  val vector2 = Vector(B(Seq( T("3"))))

returns common : Set(T(1), T(3)) which is not correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Set.intersect` might help you:

```
object FindCommon extends App {

  case class T(name: String)
  case class B(t: Seq[T])

  val vector1 = Vector(B(Seq(T("1") ,T("2") , T("3"))))
  val vector2 = Vector(B(Seq(T("1") , T("3"))))

  val f1 = vector1.flatMap(_.t).toSet
  val f2 = vector2.flatMap(_.t).toSet

  val common = f1.intersect(f2)

  println("common : "+common)
}
```

Prints: `common : Set(T(1), T(3))`

Scatie: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/htzTPHa8TPWq4xtzTjNh9g

Answer (score 2):

I like Ivan's approach using `intersect`, but here is another approach that you may also like.

```scala
def findCommon(v1: Vector[B], v2: Vector[B]): Set[T] = {
  val v2Set = v2.iterator.flatMap(_.t).toSet

  v1.iterator.flatMap(_.t).filter(v2Set.contains).toSet
}
```

You may replace `toSet` with something different like `.distinct.toList` to collect the elements as any collection you want.